# using wxpython calling frame function python interpreter returns error

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(620, 665))

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.MainPanel = NewPanel(splitter)
        self.MyNotebook = Nbook(splitter)
        splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.MainPanel, self.MyNotebook, sashPosition=210)
        self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar(3)
        self.MainPanel.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def setNotebookDisabled(self):
        self.MyNotebook.Enabled = False

    def PrintSomething(self):
        print("Something")


class NewPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(NewPanel, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def Disable_Controls(self):
        self.GrandParent.MyNotebook.Enabled = False

class Nbook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Nbook, self).__init__(parent)

        # self.MyNotebook = wx.Notebook(splitter,wx.ID_ANY)
        page_one = NbPanel1(self)
        page_two = NbPanel2(self)
        page_three = NbPanel3(self)
        self.AddPage(page_one, "Cable")
        self.AddPage(page_two, "Busduct")
        self.AddPage(page_three, "Transformer")
```

I can call PrintSomething() with success however...
 
The error:
File "c:/Users/Mark/Documents/FaultWireCalc/FCCalc.py", line 331, in Disable_Controls
    self.GrandParent.MyNotebook.Enabled = False
AttributeError: 'MyFrame' object has no attribute 'MyNotebook'

Comment: You have given us only a partial look at your code. Where is `Nbook` for example. That said, you are envoking `NewPanel` before you have declared `MyNoteBook`, so that doesn't bode well. You may get away with it but we'd have to see the rest of your code.

Comment: I updated the code to show NBook. I don't understand how envoking NewPanel before you have declared MyNoteBook is a problem. Insight please.

Comment: Also, my code is over 1000 lines and too cumbersome to post here. I've provided what I hoped would be enough to address the question. The main question for me is why i'm getting the error when I can see MyNotebook is clearly a declaration in MyFrame. Frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much an answer as a work in progress, given that a comment simply wouldn't hack it.

Given that you haven't stated when or how the error occurs and it's occurring somewhere in 1000 lines of code, which we can't see, right about now might be a good time for
`a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve)`
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

As you seem reluctant to provide one, let's try this:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(620, 665))

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.MainPanel = NewPanel(splitter)
        self.MyNotebook = Nbook(splitter)
        splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.MainPanel, self.MyNotebook, sashPosition=210)
        self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar(3)
        self.MainPanel.Show()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def setNotebookDisabled(self):
        self.MyNotebook.Enabled = False

    def PrintSomething(self):
        print("Something")


class NewPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(NewPanel, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        testbut = wx.Button(self, -1, "Panel Hit Me")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Disable_Controls)

    def Disable_Controls(self, event):
        self.GrandParent.MyNotebook.Enabled = not self.GrandParent.MyNotebook.IsEnabled()


class Nbook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Nbook, self).__init__(parent)

        # self.MyNotebook = wx.Notebook(splitter,wx.ID_ANY)
        page_one = wx.Panel(self)
        page_two = wx.Panel(self)
        page_three = wx.Panel(self)
        self.AddPage(page_one, "Cable")
        self.AddPage(page_two, "Busduct")
        self.AddPage(page_three, "Transformer")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None, "Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see, it does function (below) the notebook can be enabled/disabled.

[image]

So, can you make this produce the error or deduce from it, how your code differs in the way or when the code is called, that produces the error?

You may find that `GrandParent` is not what you think it is! (I suspect `splitter` is involved)
You might try:

```
print("I am",self)
print("My parent is",self.Parent)
print("Granddad is",self.GrandParent)
print("His parent is",self.GrandParent.GetParent())
```

The other thing you might try when calling the routine, is to call it directly:

```
MyFrame.setNotebookDisabled(parent.GetParent())
```

or a variation to get the right parent, depending on where you are calling it from.

Over to you.

Comment: @MarkOgles I'm intrigued, what suggestion above gave you the clue to solving your problem, because I was unable to pin it down.